# What is the best way to detect several buttons being clicked

Tags: iphone, c++, openframeworks

i have several circles drawn programmatically on the screen . I then work out the distance between the finger click's x and y coordinates with each of the circle's x and y coordinates.

Which ever distance is less than any of the circle's radius is the circle that was clicked on. Quite simple really. However im finding that ive got a lot of repeated code and i feel that i can clean up the code but im not sure what the best way to do it at the moment.

any help is appreciated.

```
float diffx = touch.x - bass.pos.x;
float diffy = touch.y - bass.pos.y;
float dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);
if(dist < bass.radius){

    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){
        //do some stuff related to this button unique

    }
    //play some sound
}

diffx = touch.x - treble.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - treble.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < treble.radius){
    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){
        //do something related to this button
    }
    //play some sound
}

diffx = touch.x - hihat.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - hihat.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < hihat.radius){
    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){

        //do shayt related to this button

    }
    //play this sound
}

diffx = touch.x - bassTwo.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - bassTwo.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < bassTwo.radius){
    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){
        //do some crap regarding this indivudal button

    }
    //play another sound
}

diffx = touch.x - kick.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - kick.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < kick.radius){
    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){
      //do some funky stuff related to this button
    }
    //play some sound
}

diffx = touch.x - snare.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - snare.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < snare.radius){
    if(recordingInfo.isRecording){
        //
    }
    //play some sound
}

diffx = touch.x - recordButton.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - recordButton.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);

if(dist < recordButton.radius){
    //and do some funky stuff audio visual styff gere
}    

diffx = touch.x - play.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - play.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);
     //code execution if this circle button is hit
}
```

or is this fine? i place all of this code in the touchDown method

Comment: [tag:objective-c] or [tag:c++] ?

Comment: jut put the "buttons" into a NSArray, the iterate it

Comment: lol intermediate hacker i was just looking at one of your other answers strangely enough! this is currently in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated code is:

```
diffx = touch.x - recordButton.pos.x;
diffy = touch.y - recordButton.pos.y;
dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);
```

Any time code appears more than once you should consider putting it in a function:

```
float distance(vec touch, vec button_center) {
    float diffx = touch.x - bass.pos.x;
    float diffy = touch.y - bass.pos.y;
    float dist = sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);
    return dist;
}

if(distance(touch,bass.pos) < bass.radius){
   ...
}
if(distance(touch, treble.pos) < treble.radius){
   ...
}
if(distance(touch,hihat.pos) < hihat.radius){
   ...
}
```

Of course, you're also repeating that check to see if a button has been hit:

```
bool is_hit(Button b,vec touch) {
    return distance(b.pos,touch) < b.radius;
}

if(is_hit(bass,touch)) {}
if(is_hit(treble,touch)) {}
...
```

This is a very simple method of handling events and it's hard to reduce the repetition further without changing the program's architecture. If you want something a little more flexible you might want to look into how GUI frameworks handle events. The Cocoa documentation on the events might be a good example to look at: [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, add some simple utility methods:

```
- (float) distanceBetweenTouch:(UITouch*)touch andPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    float diffx = touch.x - point.x;
    float diffy = touch.y - point.y;
    return sqrt(diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy);
}

- (NSArray*) tappedButtons:(NSArray*)buttons forTouch:(UITouch*)touch {
    NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (SomeCustomButtonType* button in buttons) {
        if ([self distanceBetweenTouch:touch andPoint:button.pos] < button.radius) {
            [result addObject:button];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then revise your code to do something like:

```
NSArray* allButtons = [NSArray* arrayWithObjects:bass, treble, hihat, ..., nil];
NSArray* tappedButtons = [self tappedButtons:allButtons forTouch:touch];

for (SomeCustomButtonType* button in tappedButtons) {
    if (button == bass) {
        //handle tap on the 'bass' button
    }
    else if (button == treble) {
        //handle tap on the 'treble' button
    }
    //... (handlers for other buttons)
}
```

...or even better, if you move the code around a bit so that each button knows what it should do when tapped, you could perhaps rewrite that `if/else` block and the `for` loop like:

```
[tappedButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(handleTap)];
```

Although, I'm not sure how a single tap will intersect with multiple buttons, unless your buttons are partially overlapping.